# Parsing email with Email::MIME and multipart/signed

Tags: perl, email, mime-types

I'm a perl novice trying to figure out how to decode a MIME-encoded email with multiple parts. I'm not sure of conventions, so I'll just include the pieces of the email that I believe are relevant:

```
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============3385789078715843912=="
 Mime-Version: 1.0

 --===============3385789078715843912==
 Content-Type: multipart/signed; micalg="pgp-sha256";
     protocol="application/pgp-signature"; boundary="=-0+dmFxz+BsFOEAAxvudu"


 --=-0+dmFxz+BsFOEAAxvudu
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

 PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09
 PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT0KVWJ1bnR1IFNlY3VyaXR5IE5vdGljZSBVU04tMzIxMC0xCkZlYnJ1
 YXJ5IDIzLCAyMDE3CgpMaWJyZU9mZmljZSB2dWxuZXJhYmlsaXR5Cj09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09
 PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09
 CgpBIHNlY3VyaXR5IGlzc3VlIGFmZmVjdHMgdGhlc2UgcmVsZWFzZXMgb2YgVWJ1bnR1IGFuZCBp
 dHMgZGVyaXZhdGl2ZXM6CgotIFVidW50dSAxNi4wNCBMVFMKLSBVYnVudHUgMTQuMDQgTFRTCi0g
```

I've got the following bit of code:

```
  my $msg = Email::MIME->new($buf);

  for my $part ($msg->parts) {
      if ($part->content_type =~ m!multipart/mixed!
              or $part->content_type eq '' )
          {   
              print "Found Multipart";
              for my $subpart ($part->parts) {
                  print $subpart->body;
             }
      }
  }
```

I really don't know what to do next. I've had a dozen different variations on this, and haven't gotten any closer after four hours of working on it. I'd appreciate if someone could help me identify the proper perl modules and functions to be used to read this text sub-part of a signed email.

Comment: Well if you manually decode the message body part at the bottom, you get proper output. That's a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of Email::MIME suggests [not to use `parts`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME#parts), because *it's a stupid method*. It returns its own object if there are no parts. That is weird.

Instead use the [`subparts` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME#subparts) to get the parts of the email. Then use it again to iterate all parts of that part. If there are any, it will go in. Print the `body` of that sub part and you're done.

```
foreach my $part ( $msg->subparts ) {
    foreach my $sub_part ($part->subparts) {
            print $sub_part->body;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've realized now I can't figure out how to process the $sub_part->body. Is this an array? Can I use join() or push() to process it line-by-line?

Comment: @AlexRegan I don't know. I've never used it myself. https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME#body says it's a byte string. It should be the full message, but in bytes. You might need to decode it. For your example, the correct text comes out.